# Document.ready не работает

Tags: jquery, javascript

Господа, подскажите из-за чего может не отрабатывать такая штука:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
        console.log('ok');
    });
```

По идее не формируется DOM дерево, но как понять где ошибка и из=за чего оно не формируется, если консоль ошибок не выдает (firebug)?

Такой код работает корректно:

```
$(window).load(function(){
       console.log('load ok');
    });
```

Comment: jQuery(document).on("ready", function(){ alert(0) });
так работает ?

Comment: Нет. Ошибок в консоли тоже не выдается.

Comment: > The .ready() method is generally incompatible with the <body onload=""> attribute. If load must be used, either do not use .ready() or use jQuery's .load() method to attach load event handlers to the window or to more specific items, like images.

посмотрите нет ли какого скрипта, который пишет что нить типа 

document.body.onload=function();

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/WGLmV/ всё работает, проверьте правильность подсключения JQ.

Comment: Очень смешно. 1) У меня $(document).ready не работает скорее всего из-за не подгруженного DOM дерева.
2) Jquery у меня подключен правильно (и я об этом упоминал как минимум вот этим: $(window).load )

Answer (score 0):

Все оказывается довольно просто. Оказывается, что если у Вас в документе есть ошибки в js в любых других функциях, или подключаемых файлах (даже самые простые например вызов несуществующего метода), то есть вероятность, что $(document).ready не отработает, т.к. видимо считает что DOM модель еще не готова. Возможно данный совет окажется кому-нибудь полезен.

Comment: вы ошибаетесь в причинах, просто тред после uncaugh exception не работает. т.е. так:

     hello.world() ; //ошибка
     console.log('Hello world'); //не выполнится

а так:

    $(function() {
      hello.world() ; //ошибка      
    });
    $(function() {
       console.log('Hello world'); //выполнится
    });

Comment: или так:

    $(function() {
       console.log('Hello world'); //выполнится
    });

    hello.world() ; //ошибка

Comment: В вопросе написано явно: "если консоль ошибок не выдает (firebug)", не понятно как комьюнити могло бы предположить наличие ошибок.